# Saving QML styles directly into QGS project file

Tags: qgis, style, qgis-3, qgs

I have a QGIS Model (saved in directly in QGIS 3 project file ".qgs") which creates some layers and assign predefined styles to them. I would like to save those QML styles into my .qgs and reference the styles there directly in my QGIS model.

Is it possible to store QML Style files directly in .qgs project? Or is there other solution to this? The new version of QGIS Project now allows to store a lot of kind of data diretcly in it.